# Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

below is my database settings but that will give me following error

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost:9880';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'codeignitor';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Can anyone tell me where i am wrong.
Please help

Comment: check your database name, is it really 'codeignitor'? or is it 'codeigniter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost:9880';
```

Your problem is there.  That's not where the port number goes.  It goes in `$db['default']['port']`.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['port'] = '9880';
```

Docs: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: both have same result